# call expf from assembly

Tags: c, function, assembly, nasm

I have a little problem. I have a C file and one assembly file. The C code is the seguent:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void powAss();

int main(int argc,char **argv){
     powAss();
     printf("Finito\n");
}
```

where the `powAss()` function is defined in the seguent assembly file:

```
global powAss

section .data

section .text
     extern expf

powAss:
push      ebp               ; salva il Base Pointer
mov ebp, esp ;il Base Pointer punta al Record di Attivazione corrente     
push    ebx             ; salva i registri da preservare
push    esi
push    edi
mov ecx,0
push ecx
call expf
pop edi                 ; ripristina i registri da preservare
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp            ; ripristina lo Stack Pointer
pop ebp                 ; ripristina il Base Pointer
ret
```

I want to do the value in ecx register to the expf function. Now, the problem is: how can i get the result of the expf function in assembly?

Comment: What is the purpose of writing `posAss` in assembly? Your code is sub-optimal, so it would not only be easier but give you better results if you just wrote the code in C.

Comment: yes i know that is better to write the code in C, but i need to do this operation in assembly

Comment: With CDECL calling convention the caller has to clean the stack of parameters pushed. Your code you `push ecx` but don't remove that parameter when you return from `expf` so it messes up the stack when the subsequent pops and the return are done.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point return values are passed on the top of the FPU stack (`st0`).

You need to define `powAss` like this

```
float powAss();
```

And then use it as usual.

This is because your assembly is calling `expf`, which then puts its return value into `st0`, and then you don't touch it until the end of the function, and the compiler will assume `st0` has the return value from the function.

Comment: With 32-bit code `expf` (_C_ library) returns a floating point value on the top of the FPU stack (`st0`), not _EAX_. It seems he is wanting to know how to utilize the floating point value in his assembly code.

Comment: it seems that the expf doesn't put the return value in st0. Maybe i have to do something else?